# Ubuntu 22.04 Wrong Application Switching (Alt + Tab) Behavior

Tags: 22.04, application-switcher

since I switched to Ubuntu 22.04 I noticed some wrong behavior when switching between certain applications.
When I have Firefox opened and press `Alt+Tab` it opens PyCharm as usual.
Now when I press `Alt+Tab` again Firefox is still in first place in the Application Switcher but the Application Switcher switches to the second Application in the row which is still PyCharm so nothing happens.

Comment: I just tried to replicate this with 22.04 LTS using the X11 Windowing System and it worked perfectly well.

Comment: I tried to replicate this on xUbuntu 22.04. It worked fine for me. Have you got any shortcut software that is intercepting the keyboard commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a corresponding [bug report for Ubuntu 22.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1971693). Updating the package `libmutter-10-0` to the most recent version `42.1-0ubuntu1` and rebooting fixed the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Here the same thing happened. I found out the shortcut had changed to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: I recommend switching the default <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> via the Keyboard settings dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Got the same issue on my laptop, I've checked the mutter package version and it was ok, try in the Ubuntu settings -> Keboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> navigation -> Switch windows
It was disabled......